# Ruby Net::HTTP can't get url right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, net-http

**The code:**

`self.response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url.strip))`

**The url:**

`http://www.apmebf.com/g7116vpyxF/pw0/EDDEGMFH/EGJFDKJ/D/D/D?h=q<<lxxt%3A%2F%2F000.htfspz0.rix%3AC4%2Fgpmgo-57A64BA-54457D68<<K<<`

Gives this **error:**

`bad URI(is not URI?)`

I tried using `URI.encode` but then it throws this **error:**

`` undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x007fc7ae31ecf0> ``

It's driving me nuts -- **any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

If you urlencode the URL you get

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apmebf.com%2Fg7116vpyxF%2Fpw0%2FEDDEGMFH%2FEGJFDKJ%2FD%2FD%2FD%3Fh%3Dq%3C%3Clxxt%253A%252F%252F000.htfspz0.rix%253AC4%252Fgpmgo-57A64BA-54457D68%3C%3CK%3C%3C
```

Ruby can't find a protocol in there, so it assumes it is a generic URI and not an HTTP-URI. Only HTTP-URIs have a `request_uri` method.

You'll have to fix that URI manually by replacing the `<` with `%3C` via `str.replace`.